# local storage problems (updating var's)

Tags: javascript, html

When I try to load in saved content from the last webpage session the number loads in but the variable dosent change which means when I press the button to add 1 to the variable instead of adding on to the last saved number it starts all the way from one.
heres the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="collectWood()">chop wood</button>
<p>wood:</p>
<p id="woodOut">0</p>
<button onclick="saveData()">save Data</button>
<button onclick="loadData()">load Data</button>
<script>
var wood = localStorage.getItem;

//saves game data
function saveData() {
 localStorage.setItem("woodSave", wood);
}
function loadData() {
 document.getElementById('woodOut').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("woodSave");
}
//outputs one wood when button is clicked
function collectWood() {
 wood = wood + 1;
 document.getElementById("woodOut").innerHTML = wood;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you mean `var wood = localStorage.getItem('woodOut')`; ? Otherwise the `wood` variable is a reference to the `getItem` function (which you can't save later, because the `setItem` accepts **only** strings).

Comment: Aside from the above, you'll also want to parse the value you get from local storage: `var wood = +localStorage.getItem("woodSave");` Since it's a string, but you are apparently using it as a number, you'll need to do that or later when you do `wood = wood + 1` you'll end up with string concatenation (`"5"` becomes `"51"`), not addition.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! but when i click the load data button after saving the data and reloading the webpage instead of adding one to the amount i had loaded in from last session the counter starts from zero.

Comment: After `var wood =getItem("woodSave");`  at the start of script , add `document.getElementById("woodOut").innerHTML = parseInt(wood);` also before using any variable  check is needed to see if value exists but i'll leave that to you

Comment: Thank you guys so much! You solved another problem too! You're life savers!